# Dialogflow: Recently Added Intents are not being triggered

Tags: dialogflow-es

I've been trying to debug a problem with our Dialogflow agent for a while now, and have been running up against a mysterious error. I'm interfacing to DF using the NodeJS client,  though I believe the issue lies with the platform itself.

None of the intents that I have added in the past week are being triggered, even when a text that matches a training phrase is entered and the contexts match. Currently, I am creating new intents using the web console interface, and then communicating with the bot using the nodeJS API.

I have tried modifying the lifespans of the context to make sure they are not interfering with one another, and also have ensured that the text on each intent is sufficiently specific as to prevent interference.

The most recent test I have tried is to run a query in the Dialogflow console itself, having reset all contexts. (I also notice the mysterious appearence of a context called system_counters, which I don't believe was there before) The results are shown below: despite the query being a verbatim training phrase (the training phrases are specific, and definitely dissimilar to training phrases for other intents for this agent).

[image: trying to trigger an intent through the console]

I do not believe that this project has exceeded a quota limit. There are currently around 25 intents, and fewer than 20 training phrases per agent.

Meanwhile all previously written intents continue to work fine, and I am able to change and update training and response phrases without issue. They are of equal (if not greater) complexity to the ones added recently.

The only issue I can think of that has changed the account in the past week or so is that we created a service account that can manage multiple agents simultaneously. This is necessary for our application, as we're running a serverless site which can only store one private key as a process variable. This itself was discussed on the Google forums, and was a solution that others had successfully used. I can't think why that would affect the adding of intents, though, especially as everything else continues to work as expected.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The same problem I ran through weeks ago. I have tried multiple things, but I am not sure which one has fixed this issue. I also believe this is the issue with the platform. Please try out the below things.

1. Manually do hard training for agents from **settings**
2. I have deleted a few intents that were not working and added them again.
3. I have also changed the intent name those were not working.

in the end, things were up and running as expected. If not you can write to the Dialogflow support team, they are very active and surely help with the right steps.

Comment: Thanks Abhinav, that's really helpful. May I ask: was it all new intents, or just a few? And - how did you contact the support team?

Comment: No, I have deleted, all the new ones, because hardly I had 10 at that time. You can connect with dialog flow team with support@dialogflow.com

Comment: I have the exact same problem. I started to play with  context variables and adding  one or two new intents. Now I have one specific intent that is never associated with any text input including exact matches. 13 intents so far.

Comment: Follow-up: removing the input context variable fixed the problem. Weird.